# Can't open perl script "Build.PL": No such file or directory in response to perl Build.PL

Tags: perl

I'm very new to Perl. I have tried to install BioPerl with the instructions on https://bioperl.org/INSTALL.html. Everything worked fine till the command "perl Build.PL" to which I got the error message "Can't open perl script "Build.PL": No such file or directory". Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks! (I tried this on both Ubuntu and Windows platforms and got the same problem with the perl Build.PL command)

Answer (score 2):

> Can't open perl script "Build.PL": No such file or directory

`Build.PL` is a perl script, and you're feeding that script to perl to run it. In order to run it, you have to be in the directory where the script can be found. Perl does not go looking for the script. You can verify the files are in the same directory using `ls` (from the terminal).

Judging from those install instructions, you forgot

```
cd bioperl-live
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm actually in bioperl-live. This is the pathway on my terminal:
/Desktop/PAML/BioPerl/bioperl-live-master$ perl Build.PL
I went through all the folders in bioperl-live and couldn't find a script with "Build". Is there any way I can get this script separately?

Comment: run this `find . -type f -name 'Build*'`

Comment: I did. I does not show anything, just goes on to the next command line

(base) lab@lab-Precision-Tower:~/Desktop/PAML/BioPerl/bioperl-live-master$ find . -type f -name 'Build*'
(base) lab@lab-Precision-Tower:~/Desktop/PAML/BioPerl/bioperl-live-master$

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to install a [Dist-Zilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla) based distribution.

Try to install like this:

```
cd bioperl-live
cpanm Dist::Zilla
dzil authordeps --missing | cpanm
dzil install
```

**NOTES**:

- When I tried this, I was not able to install the dependency [`DB_File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DB_File) due to missing headers. These header files could be installed by running

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libdb-dev
  ```
- The dependency [`XML::DOM::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::DOM::XPath) refused to install due to [a failed test](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=115098). This was worked around by manually skipping the tests:

  ```
  cpanm --notest XML::DOM::XPath
  ```